# Primality predicate in Haskell

Tags: haskell, primes

I wrote a primality test for [UniHaskell](https://github.com/totallyhuman/unihaskell) however, it seems complicated in terms of conditionals.

Here it is, rewritten to not use Unicode and other functions in the code:

```
-- Primality predicate
isPrime  :: Int -> Bool
isPrime 2 = True
isPrime 3 = True
isPrime n
    | n `mod` 2 == 0 = False
    | n `mod` 3 == 0 = False
    | otherwise      = check 5 2
  where check i w
            | i * i <= n = if n `mod` i == 0
                           then False
                           else check (i + w) (6 - w)
            | otherwise = True
```

The algorithm is simple: return `True` if `n` is **2** or **3**, `False` if `n` is a multiple of **2** or **3**, and then perform trial division over numbers that are not multiples of **2** or **3**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All in all, that is some good looking, idiomatic Haskell. Well done!

---

You seem to be using the `mod n x == 0` idiom quite often, so let's extract that to its own function.

```
divides :: Integral a => a -> a -> Bool
n `divides` m = m `mod` n == 0
```

---

You could also make your predicate polymorphic. No need to restrict yourself to `Int`, any `Integral` will do the trick.

```
isPrime :: Integral a => a -> Bool
isPrime 2 = True
-- and so on
```

---

I've often read that `rem` is faster than `mod`, but I've never checked... maybe it does give you some speed.

---

Through clever reordering of the guards, you can get rid of the `if then else`.

---

Instead of having a simple comment to explain the function, consider writing actual [Haddock](https://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/index.html) documentation.

---

Putting it together:

```
-- | @divides n m@ checks whether @n@ evenly
--   divides @m@, meaning that @m `mod` n == 0@.
divides :: Integral a => a -> a -> Bool
n `divides` m = m `rem` n == 0


-- | Checks whether a given number is prime.
isPrime :: Integral a => a -> Bool    
isPrime 2 = True
isPrime 3 = True
isPrime n 
    | 2 `divides` n = False
    | 3 `divides` n = False 
    | otherwise     = check 5 2 
  where check i w 
      | i * i > n     = True
      | i `divides` n = False
      | otherwise     = check (i + w) (6 - w)
```

Maybe `check 5 2` deserves a comment, as I couldn't see why these numbers are there on a first glance.

Answer (score -1):

[Replace recursion by control structures.](https://gist.github.com/Gurkenglas/b662d4889a0db8eeceaf66f558b611e8)

```
isPrime n = elem n [2,3] || all ((/=0) . mod n)
  (takeWhile (\i -> i * i <= n) $ 2 : 3 : concat [[i, i+2] | i <- [5,11..]])
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is an improvement? I find the original code easier to understand.

Comment: Looking at the original code without its name or comments, it took me a while to understand why it shuffled around the numbers the way it did in check, so I made the code say explicitly that it runs a check on a bunch of numbers.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Why don’t you include that in your answer? I think more could be learned from it if it *explained* more, instead of merely *showing*.

Comment: That's what "Replace recursion by control structures." is for. A good heuristic for whether code shuffles its numbers around in a confusing way is whether it is recursive. Structures such as lists can classify the form of recursion used. I shall start including explanatory links.